# Android - Test Google Play Billing with fake or real card?

Tags: android, google-pay

I have followed instructions given [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing) to test Google Play Billing, however I am not sure when we test, do we enter our real credit card information?? Our do we put fake credit card information? If we put fake credit card information, where can I get this fake credit card?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, well testing is part of development, for me your comment and your close vote are useless and counterproductive